# how can i get character from string with pointers c++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, character

how to make a program to take 4 letters from the front where the word you input has 10 letters, with the words free with pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string phrase;
    cout << "Input : ";
    cin >> phrase;
    cout << "Output: " << phrase.substr(0, 4);
    // i dont know how to use pointers
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do like that to the output but use pointers, what can I do?

Comment: It would seem `// i dont know how to use pointers` is the real problem here. A good book on the language will show you this, and much, *much* more. Strongly urge you to invest in one, or check out your local library. Fwiw, if reasonable and not required, you generally wouldn't use them for this task anyway. There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown (lack of any IO error checking notwithstanding).

Comment: What about https://onlinegdb.com/uS_Ko_oip

Comment: *"..., with the words free with pointers"* - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to do like that to the output but **use pointers**, what can I do?

Given that the input string at least `10` characters long, you can use `std::string::c_str` as shown below:

```
const char* bPtr = phrase.c_str();
const char* ePtr = phrase.c_str() + 4;
std::string result(bPtr, ePtr);
    
cout << "Output: " << result;
```

Or a one liner:

```
std::string result(phrase.c_str(), phrase.c_str() + 4);
```

Or

```
std::string result(phrase.c_str(), 4);
```

Note that you can also use iterators using `std::string::begin` instead of pointers.

```
std::string result(phrase.begin(), phrase.begin() + 4);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding OP's question, but I would rather use `.begin()` to get an iterator instead of the raw pointer, unless I really need a c string. Also if you do use `.c_str()`, you could construct the new string with `result(phrase.c_str(), 4)`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I was thinking of using iterators from `.begin()` but then i decided not to use them as in OP's question pointers were mentioned and not iterators. Similarly, i was also thinking of using `result(phrase.c_str(), 4)` but then i decided not to. Since you've mentioned it in the comment, i've updated my answer by including both of these. Check out the updated asnwer.